# window.open in web application for iPad running in fullscreen replaces the existing window

Tags: asp.net, ipad, fullscreen, back, window.open

I am writing a simple (ASP.NET) web application for the iPad. It is written and works well however one feature is it serving up PDF files (among others). To do this I used window.open to open the file.

When this is done in Safari, it works perfectly. You click the button, the file opens in a new tab; you can then close the tab to return to the previous web page.

However now running the application in fullscreen mode - i.e. with the appropriate "meta names" set and from a shortcut on the home screen - when you click the button to load the file, it loads fullscreen with no means to get back to the last page.

Because it is a file, not a webpage, I can't put a "Back" button on, and when you press the iPad button it simply closes the whole thing.

I know this has been asked before and I have read a number of similar questions - the closest of which was this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168236/web-app-hyperlinks

If at all possible, it would be far preferable (thanks to the control library I am using) that the button click is done with javascript - it is not easy to set the link href.

The upshot is I really I just want to create a new window from within a fullscreen iPad web application, or allow the "back" navigation somehow...

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create an iframe on your page rather than using an `window.open` and set that as the target.

That way your pdf would open within your existing window.

Use some client side javascript like jQuery to style it like a [dialog window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: Well - that sort of works. It's a brilliant idea, but comes with two problems. The first is this: [link](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/blog/2012/05/strategies-for-the-iframe-on-the-ipad-problem/) - the second is it doesnt seem to render PDF files in an iframe very well - it's almost impossible to set the width and height and more importantly it just renders a block of gray almost all the time until you really scroll around and clikc everything lots of times...!

Comment: I've screenshotted what I mean by the gray [here](http://i.imgur.com/9NUJc.png) - this is what you see when you scroll down - on initial load all you can see is gray, but as you scroll it starts to reveal it - if you rotate, it draws it properly!